# High wa but no IO usage

Tags: linux, performance, vps, performance-monitoring, load-average

My VPS is having extremely high wa (around 90), but there is no IO usage taking place.

htop:
[image]

iotop:
[image]

nethogs:
[image]

What can be the problem here?

Comment: Please don't post terminal output as pictures, it's really hard to read. Instead just copy-paste the actual text. If you put 4 spaces first on the line, it'll be properly formatted as code, keeping the font monospace.

Comment: @JennyD I have summarized their content, they basically mean no io usage and no network-bandwidth usage, but high waiting for io. Copying them is hard because they are kind of graphical and will lose their typesetting when copied.

Comment: @HappyFace: No, they will not if you do it correctly. https://serverfault.com/editing-help

Comment: So what is the question? YOu know how the hardware look and how busy it is? If not -  there is nothing left. "Help, i can not buy a bus ticket, I only need 1" - yeah, the bus is already sold out. High IO wait on a VPS = storage subsystem ON THE HARDWARE is busy.

Comment: @TomTom So the problem is with the VPS’s host?

Comment: Obviously, or? What else can it be?

Comment: @TomTom I’m a novice, nothing is obvious to me :) I have seen so many counterintuitive things in life that I rather ask the experts first. Thanks.

Comment: Then off to superuser.com or hire an admin. And stating the obvious: novice does not mean common sense should not apply. A vps still runs on hardware that still has limits. If you do not use it, what about the others? Common sense.

Comment: @TomTom But the host being busy shouldn't produce high iowait values inside the VM with no visible I/O or network activity (there should be at least _some_ I/O in progress for iowait to be nonzero).  It _might_ manifest as high KVM steal time, but that is accounted differently and displayed differently by htop.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Except if youlook at the screenshots I see SOME - little but some - IO. So, "no visible IO" does not sound right. One write per second already can wait crazy. Yeah, something is odd - but then this is likely a low end machine ona low end hoster. Which means the hoster should know, out of a VM you can not know.